# Seeking an example of potential.

Tags: mathematical-modeling, potential-theory, celestial-mechanics

Consider a compact Lie group (the dimension of the group is greater than 1) and a representation $R^n$ of the group G. 

I am seeking an example of potential $p: R^n \rightarrow R$ which is invariant under the action of the group G such that $p’(v_0)=0$ and the isotropy group of $v_0$ is not trivial. 

If anyone knows this kind of potentials for instance in celestial mechanics,  biology or chemistry.

I know for example Newtonian potential of the N-body problem but isotropy groups of noncollinear central configurations are trivial.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).